# how to access other class in same swift framwork?

Tags: ios, class, swift, public

In my swift framework, I define two class , call A and B, but it build for error.

```
 // in a.swift
 public class A : NSObject {
    public var count
    public override init() {
          count = 10
    }
 }

 // in b.swift
 public class B : NSObject {
    public func getACount(a:A) {     // error : use undeclare type : A
        println(a.count)
    }
    public override init() {

    }
 }
```

why it cannot output this error?

Comment: You have to create a variable in class B with a type A, and store a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the type of `var count` to `Int` in class `A`.

Is this what you want?

```
public class A : NSObject {
    public var count: Int
    public override init() {
        count = 10
        super.init()
    }
}

public class B : NSObject {
    public func getACount(a:A) {     // error : use undeclare type : A
        println(a.count)
    }
}


var b = B()
var a = A()
var aa = A()
aa.count = 123


b.getACount(a) // prints 10
b.getACount(aa) // prints 123
```

Also if you override an `init()` make sure you call `super.init()` to make sure the parent class initialises.

Comment: I only build this framework , it can build success, but when I buill with other , it show the "use undeclare type : A" again.

Comment: @MJ000111 can you be more specific, on what you did?